# Suppose there are m men and w women to attend a concert, all to be seated at the front row.

Tags: probability

Suppose there are m men and w women to attend a concert, all to be seated at the front row. What is the probability all of the women will be sitting next to one another if it is equally likely for anyone to pick any seat?

I am completely lost. Since there are no numbers, obviously this will be represented in terms of m and w

Comment: The required answer is $\frac {(m+1)!} {(m+w)!}.$

Answer (score 0):

How many ways are there to put all the people in order?  That is your denominator.  How many ways to put the women in order?  How many ways to choose where the first one sits?  How many ways to put the men in order around them?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be treated with the following:
The M men are supposed to be placed without any restrictions on the seats, but the W women, as they are supposed to sit side by side on the chairs, will be considered as an united body with an internal mathematical permutation. So we have:

P= ((M+1)!W!)/((M+W)!)
like following Pic
[image]

Indeed you can solve the problem with simple numbers for M, W, (say M=2 , W=2) and then extend the solution.

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Number the seats from $1$ to $m+w,$ left to right.  The leftmost woman must occupy one of seats $1$ through $m+1,$ so there are $m+1$ ways for the women to sit together.  (Alternatively, there are from $0$ to $m$ men to the left of the women.)

There are ${m+w\choose w}$ ways to select the seats the women will occupy with no restrictions, so the answer is $${m+1\over{m+w\choose w}}= {(m+1)!w!\over(m+w)!}$$